Where in android flutter do i make changes to get rid of this warning?
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

In your Android Studio, you need to update your Android SDK Command-line Tools to latest. Moreover, you have to make your Android Studio and CMD-line tools aligned with each other. You have to try to update your Android Studio if it wasn't yet updated.
